# get valules for all fields from selected features

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, visual-studio

The following code works for retrieving values within a particular field(Name1), but I want to retrieve mulitple fields.  Am I to create multiple variables for each field?

```
IMxDocument pMxDocument = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IMap pMap = pMxDocument.FocusMap;
        ILayer pLayer = pMap.get_Layer(0);
        IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)pLayer;
        IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;

        ITable pTable = (ITable)pFeatureClass;
        ICursor pCursor = pTable.Search(null, false);
        int fldIndex = pFeatureClass.Fields.FindField("Name1");
        IRow pRow = pCursor.NextRow();
        while (pRow != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(pRow.get_Value(fldIndex).ToString());
            pRow = pCursor.NextRow();

        }
```

Edit:  What I'm trying to do is get the selected features of a feature class, get the values for fields like Name, address, city, etc and then pass those values onto a document.  I thought I would give some background to what I am doing since I may be on the wrong track to start off with.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two examples of getting values from the selected features.

This one lists all the values for the feature

```
IMxDocument pMxDocument = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
IMap pMap = pMxDocument.FocusMap;
ILayer pLayer = pMap.get_Layer(0);
IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)pLayer;
IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;
IFields pFields = (IFields)pFeatureClass;
ITable pTable = (ITable)pFeatureClass;
ICursor pCursor = pTable.Search(null, false);
IRow pRow = pCursor.NextRow();
while (pRow != null)
{
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(output);
    for (int i = 0; i <= pFields.FieldCount - 1; i++) {
        output += pFields.Field(i).Name + ": " + pRow.Value(i).ToString + Constants.vbNewLine;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(pRow.get_Value(fldIndex).ToString());
    pRow = pCursor.NextRow();

}
```

This example lists just selected values of the feature

```
    IMxDocument pMxDocument = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
IMap pMap = pMxDocument.FocusMap;
ILayer pLayer = pMap.get_Layer(0);
IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)pLayer;
IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;
IFields pFields = (IFields)pFeatureClass;
ITable pTable = (ITable)pFeatureClass;
ICursor pCursor = pTable.Search(null, false);
string[] FieldNames = {"Name", "Address", "City"};
string output = null;
IRow pRow = pCursor.NextRow();
while (pRow != null)
{
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(output);
    foreach (string fieldName in FieldNames) {
        output += fieldName + ": " + pRow.Value(pFields.FindField(fieldName)).ToString + Constants.vbNewLine;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(output);
    pRow = pCursor.NextRow();

}
```

Comment: I think KFP needs selected features, not selected fields."What I'm trying to do is get the **selected features** of a feature class"

Answer (score 3):

I use following code snippet to get selected features from map for a specific feature layer:

```
public List<IFeature> GetSelectedFeatures(IFeatureLayer featureLayer)
{
    IFeatureSelection featureSelection = (IFeatureSelection)featureLayer;
    var selectionSet = featureSelection.SelectionSet;
    IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
    string shapeField = featureClass.ShapeFieldName;
    ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
    spatialFilter.GeometryField = shapeField;
    spatialFilter.set_OutputSpatialReference(shapeField, _map.SpatialReference);

    ICursor cursor;
    selectionSet.Search(spatialFilter, false, out cursor);
    var featureCursor = cursor as IFeatureCursor;
    var features = new List<IFeature>();

    IFeature feature;
    while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
        features.Add((feature));

    return features;
}
```

To know more about selection you can go through [IFeatureSelection Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureSelection_Interface/0012000004ww000000/).

And as kenbuja says, you can copy fields by iterating through rows.